# Parsing an XML file properly for CSV output

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've built out this script that is meant to parse an XML file and retrieve the contents of the id, created-date, author-id and comments nodes and print them to a CSV. It's *mostly* working with one exception...

I'm running into a problem where the script is looping through every id in the XML and printing every comment in the XML as if it were part of that id when it isn't the case.

Ideally, the end goal is to only obtain and print comments that belong to each unique id and print the contents of the comment nodes.

Example of the issue (CSV output):

```
Ticket ID,Created Date,Author ID,Comment
992,2016-06-21,232245,"Hi, this is what is happening."
992,2016-06-22,231122,"This is another comment from the same id."
996,2016-06-21,232245,"Hi, this is what is happening."
996,2016-06-22,231122."This is another comment from the same id."
```

I would just like to print comments only associated with id's and not every comment with every id (if that makes any sense).

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys

from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import csv

xml_file = sys.argv[1]

if not xml_file.endswith('.xml'):
    print "%s is not a valid XML file. Exiting." % xml_file
    exit()

tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
root = tree.getroot()

# Ignore characters/string(s) (if any)
ignore_chars = ['>', '>>']


class RotateFile(object):
    def __init__(self, directory='', filename='', max_files=sys.maxint,
                 max_file_size='', header=''):
        self.ii = 1
        self.header = header
        self.directory, self.filename = directory, filename
        self.max_file_size, self.max_files = max_file_size, max_files
        self.finished, self.fh = False, None
        self.open()

    def rotate(self):
        """Rotate the file, if necessary"""
        if (os.stat(self.filename_template).st_size > self.max_file_size):
            self.close()
            self.ii += 1
            if (self.ii <= self.max_files):
                self.open()
            else:
                self.close()
                self.finished = True

    def open(self):
        self.fh = open(self.filename_template, 'w')
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.fh)
        self.writer.writerow(self.header)

    def write(self, text=""):
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.fh)
        self.writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in text])
        self.fh.flush()
        self.rotate()

    def close(self):
        self.fh.close()

    @property
    def filename_template(self):
        return "%0.2d" % self.ii + "_" + self.filename


def comments():
    for comment in root.iter('comment'):
        created_at = comment.find("created-at").text
        value = comment.find("value").text
        author_id = comment.find("author-id").text
        if not value:
            continue
        yield created_at, value, author_id


def tickets(root):
    for ticket in root.iter('ticket'):
        nice_id = ticket.find("nice-id").text
        for comment in comments():
            created_at, value, author_id = comment
            yield nice_id, created_at, author_id, value


# Set arguments
args = {'directory': '',
        'filename': 'output.csv',
        'max_file_size': 10485760,
        'header': ['Ticket ID', 'Created Date', 'Author ID', 'Comment'],
        }

fout = RotateFile(**args)

for row in tickets(root):
    if not any(ignore_chars in row for ignore_char in ignore_chars):
        print ','.join(row)
        fout.write(row)
```

Much appreciated in advance, all.

Comment: I was able to resolve this by making changes to comments(). I changed root.find to ticket.find and passed the current ticket into that function. Meaning that instead of finding all comments each time it was called, it only finds the comments inside the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code changes that were made to mend the original problem, as noted in the comment above:

```
def comments(ticket):
for comment in ticket.iter('comment'):
    created_at = comment.find("created-at").text
    value = comment.find("value").text
    author_id = comment.find("author-id").text
    if not value:
        continue
    yield created_at, value, author_id
```